# How to get last row google sheet cell formula value into variable and replace the google doc place holder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a tenancy agreement form in google word doc where I have frequently change fields. I had created a google form where I take input and using script editor which i had taken from help. Now I have a "RentAmount" field where I input amount and want to automatically convert the Amount in words like $1000 should convert in "One Thousand" I also manage to convert in google sheet by using the formula "https://www.xelplus.com/Excel-Formula-Convert-Numbers-to-Words/" and after converting I want to get the formula value in variable to place the converted text to word doc place holder. Please help

```
    function autoFillGoogleDocFromForm(e) {  
   var timestamp = e.values[0];
   var date_Dayof = e.values[1];
   var month = e.values[2];
   var ownername_MR_MRS_MS = e.values[3];
   var RentAmount = e.values[4];  
   var file = DriveApp.getFileById('fileid');  
   var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('folderid')
   var copy = file.makeCopy(ownername_MR_MRS_MS, folder);  
   var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());  
   var body = doc.getBody();
   body.replaceText("{{Date_Day_of}}", date_Dayof);
   body.replaceText('{{Month}}', month);
   body.replaceText("{{Owner_Name_MR/MRS/MS}}", ownername_MR_MRS_MS);
   body.replaceText('{{Rent Amount}}', RentAmount);
   doc.saveAndClose(); 
}
```

Comment: Please explain which is the step where you need help. Is there any issue wiht your code? Any error message? Can you retrieve the e.values correctly?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have no issue with the code it is working properly. I just need help to modify code to get the formula value to store in a variable and replace in google sheet place holder. please refer my requirement again.

Comment: So you have an additional column in your spreadsheet that takes in `RentAmount` and outputs the value in words after applying the formula? In which column ist his formula located?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The column is "T"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your formula is

> =CHOOSE(LEFT(TEXT(B3,"000000000.00"))+1,,"One","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine")
> &IF(--LEFT(TEXT(B3,"000000000.00"))=0,,IF(AND(--MID(TEXT(B3,"000000000.00"),2,1)=0,--MID(TEXT(B3,"000000000.00"),3,1)=0)," Hundred"," Hundred and "))
> &CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(B3,"000000000.00"),2,1)+1,,,"Twenty ","Thirty ","Forty ","Fifty ","Sixty ","Seventy ","Eighty ","Ninety ")
> &IF(--MID(TEXT(B3,"000000000.00"),2,1)<>1,CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(B3,"000000000.00"),3,1)+1,,"One","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine"),
> CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(B3,"000000000.00"),3,1)+1,"Ten","Eleven","Twelve","Thirteen","Fourteen","Fifteen","Sixteen","Seventeen","Eighteen","Nineteen"))
> &IF((--LEFT(TEXT(B3,"000000000.00"))+MID(TEXT(B3,"000000000.00"),2,1)+MID(TEXT(B3,"000000000.00"),3,1))=0,,IF(AND((--MID(TEXT(B3,"000000000.00"),4,1)+MID(TEXT(B3,"000000000.00"),5,1)+MID(TEXT(B3,"000000000.00"),6,1)+MID(TEXT(B3,"000000000.00"),7,1))=0,(--MID(TEXT(B3,"000000000.00"),8,1)+RIGHT(TEXT(B3,"000000000.00")))>0)," Million and "," Million "))
> &CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(B3,"000000000.00"),4,1)+1,,"One","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine")
> &IF(--MID(TEXT(B3,"000000000.00"),4,1)=0,,IF(AND(--MID(TEXT(B3,"000000000.00"),5,1)=0,--MID(TEXT(B3,"000000000.00"),6,1)=0)," Hundred"," Hundred and"))
> &CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(B3,"000000000.00"),5,1)+1,,," Twenty"," Thirty"," Forty"," Fifty"," Sixty"," Seventy"," Eighty"," Ninety")
> &IF(--MID(TEXT(B3,"000000000.00"),5,1)<>1,CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(B3,"000000000.00"),6,1)+1,," One"," Two"," Three"," Four"," Five"," Six"," Seven"," Eight"," Nine"),CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(B3,"000000000.00"),6,1)+1," Ten"," Eleven"," Twelve"," Thirteen"," Fourteen"," Fifteen"," Sixteen"," Seventeen"," Eighteen"," Nineteen"))
> &IF((--MID(TEXT(B3,"000000000.00"),4,1)+MID(TEXT(B3,"000000000.00"),5,1)+MID(TEXT(B3,"000000000.00"),6,1))=0,,IF(OR((--MID(TEXT(B3,"000000000.00"),7,1)+MID(TEXT(B3,"000000000.00"),8,1)+MID(TEXT(B3,"000000000.00"),9,1))=0,--MID(TEXT(B3,"000000000.00"),7,1)<>0)," Thousand "," Thousand and "))
> &CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(B3,"000000000.00"),7,1)+1,,"One","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine")
> &IF(--MID(TEXT(B3,"000000000.00"),7,1)=0,,IF(AND(--MID(TEXT(B3,"000000000.00"),8,1)=0,--MID(TEXT(B3,"000000000.00"),9,1)=0)," Hundred "," Hundred and "))&
> CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(B3,"000000000.00"),8,1)+1,,,"Twenty ","Thirty ","Forty ","Fifty ","Sixty ","Seventy ","Eighty ","Ninety ")
> &IF(--MID(TEXT(B3,"000000000.00"),8,1)<>1,CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(B3,"000000000.00"),9,1)+1,,"One","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine"),CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(B3,"000000000.00"),9,1)+1,"Ten","Eleven","Twelve","Thirteen","Fourteen","Fifteen","Sixteen","Seventeen","Eighteen","Nineteen")),

you can implement it into your existing code as following:

```js
function autoFillGoogleDocFromForm(e) {  
  var timestamp = e.values[0];
  var date_Dayof = e.values[1];
  var month = e.values[2];
  var ownername_MR_MRS_MS = e.values[" + row + "];
  var RentAmount = e.values[4]; 
  var column = 20; // column T
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  sheet.getRange(row, column).setFormula("=CHOOSE(LEFT(TEXT(B" + row + ",\"000000000.00\"))+1,,\"One\",\"Two\",\"Three\",\"Four\",\"Five\",\"Six\",\"Seven\",\"Eight\",\"Nine\")\r\n&IF(--LEFT(TEXT(B" + row + ",\"000000000.00\"))=0,,IF(AND(--MID(TEXT(B" + row + ",\"000000000.00\"),2,1)=0,--MID(TEXT(B" + row + ",\"000000000.00\")," + row + ",1)=0),\" Hundred\",\" Hundred and \"))\r\n&CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(B" + row + ",\"000000000.00\"),2,1)+1,,,\"Twenty \",\"Thirty \",\"Forty \",\"Fifty \",\"Sixty \",\"Seventy \",\"Eighty \",\"Ninety \")\r\n&IF(--MID(TEXT(B" + row + ",\"000000000.00\"),2,1)<>1,CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(B" + row + ",\"000000000.00\")," + row + ",1)+1,,\"One\",\"Two\",\"Three\",\"Four\",\"Five\",\"Six\",\"Seven\",\"Eight\",\"Nine\"),\r\nCHOOSE(MID(TEXT(B" + row + ",\"000000000.00\")," + row + ",1)+1,\"Ten\",\"Eleven\",\"Twelve\",\"Thirteen\",\"Fourteen\",\"Fifteen\",\"Sixteen\",\"Seventeen\",\"Eighteen\",\"Nineteen\"))\r\n&IF((--LEFT(TEXT(B" + row + ",\"000000000.00\"))+MID(TEXT(B" + row + ",\"000000000.00\"),2,1)+MID(TEXT(B" + row + ",\"000000000.00\")," + row + ",1))=0,,IF(AND((--MID(TEXT(B" + row + ",\"000000000.00\"),4,1)+MID(TEXT(B" + row + ",\"000000000.00\"),5,1)+MID(TEXT(B" + row + ",\"000000000.00\"),6,1)+MID(TEXT(B" + row + ",\"000000000.00\"),7,1))=0,(--MID(TEXT(B" + row + ",\"000000000.00\"),8,1)+RIGHT(TEXT(B" + row + ",\"000000000.00\")))>0),\" Million and \",\" Million \"))\r\n&CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(B" + row + ",\"000000000.00\"),4,1)+1,,\"One\",\"Two\",\"Three\",\"Four\",\"Five\",\"Six\",\"Seven\",\"Eight\",\"Nine\")\r\n&IF(--MID(TEXT(B" + row + ",\"000000000.00\"),4,1)=0,,IF(AND(--MID(TEXT(B" + row + ",\"000000000.00\"),5,1)=0,--MID(TEXT(B" + row + ",\"000000000.00\"),6,1)=0),\" Hundred\",\" Hundred and\"))\r\n&CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(B" + row + ",\"000000000.00\"),5,1)+1,,,\" Twenty\",\" Thirty\",\" Forty\",\" Fifty\",\" Sixty\",\" Seventy\",\" Eighty\",\" Ninety\")\r\n&IF(--MID(TEXT(B" + row + ",\"000000000.00\"),5,1)<>1,CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(B" + row + ",\"000000000.00\"),6,1)+1,,\" One\",\" Two\",\" Three\",\" Four\",\" Five\",\" Six\",\" Seven\",\" Eight\",\" Nine\"),CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(B" + row + ",\"000000000.00\"),6,1)+1,\" Ten\",\" Eleven\",\" Twelve\",\" Thirteen\",\" Fourteen\",\" Fifteen\",\" Sixteen\",\" Seventeen\",\" Eighteen\",\" Nineteen\"))\r\n&IF((--MID(TEXT(B" + row + ",\"000000000.00\"),4,1)+MID(TEXT(B" + row + ",\"000000000.00\"),5,1)+MID(TEXT(B" + row + ",\"000000000.00\"),6,1))=0,,IF(OR((--MID(TEXT(B" + row + ",\"000000000.00\"),7,1)+MID(TEXT(B" + row + ",\"000000000.00\"),8,1)+MID(TEXT(B" + row + ",\"000000000.00\"),9,1))=0,--MID(TEXT(B" + row + ",\"000000000.00\"),7,1)<>0),\" Thousand \",\" Thousand and \"))\r\n&CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(B" + row + ",\"000000000.00\"),7,1)+1,,\"One\",\"Two\",\"Three\",\"Four\",\"Five\",\"Six\",\"Seven\",\"Eight\",\"Nine\")\r\n&IF(--MID(TEXT(B" + row + ",\"000000000.00\"),7,1)=0,,IF(AND(--MID(TEXT(B" + row + ",\"000000000.00\"),8,1)=0,--MID(TEXT(B" + row + ",\"000000000.00\"),9,1)=0),\" Hundred \",\" Hundred and \"))&\r\nCHOOSE(MID(TEXT(B" + row + ",\"000000000.00\"),8,1)+1,,,\"Twenty \",\"Thirty \",\"Forty \",\"Fifty \",\"Sixty \",\"Seventy \",\"Eighty \",\"Ninety \")\r\n&IF(--MID(TEXT(B" + row + ",\"000000000.00\"),8,1)<>1,CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(B" + row + ",\"000000000.00\"),9,1)+1,,\"One\",\"Two\",\"Three\",\"Four\",\"Five\",\"Six\",\"Seven\",\"Eight\",\"Nine\"),CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(B" + row + ",\"000000000.00\"),9,1)+1,\"Ten\",\"Eleven\",\"Twelve\",\"Thirteen\",\"Fourteen\",\"Fifteen\",\"Sixteen\",\"Seventeen\",\"Eighteen\",\"Nineteen\"))");
  var formulaValue = sheet.getRange(row, column).getDisplayValue();
  Logger.log(formulaValue);
  // do what your want with formulaValue
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, I will apply your code and let you know the outcome.

Comment: Dear Ziganotschka, the code is working but there is some problem in formula. please note when 99000000 it shows Ninety  Million and missing Nine, when inputting 1000000 it is showing nothing the cell is blank, when inputting 989999998 it is showing Nine Hundred and Eighty  Million Nine Hundred and Ninety Nine Thousand Nine Hundred and Ninety Eight, here again Nine is missing. Well when using the actual formula it is working correctly. Please help me to correct the formula in script or it is requested to correct the same. Appreciate your feedback.

Comment: I took the formula from the URL you provided. If you already have a column with a formula that works better for you -you do not need to set the formula manually by script and can just skip the line `sheet.getRange(row, column).setFormula...`

Comment: thanks for the reply and suggestion. But as per your previous msg. on 12th Nov. the formula you mentioned from the URL is not similar in script. Well I will check with your given suggestion and will let you know the outcome. Thank you again.

Comment: Dear Ziganotschka, I had manually copied the formula in google sheet and after skipping the line in script and upon execution the formula cell become empty but the RentAmount is there. Can u help.

Comment: Pls note I had also applied the formula in the script but it is showing error in line 31

Comment: I had the same issue - I assume that on new form submit the cell with the formula gets overwritten. This is why I set the formula manually with the script. I took the formula from your reference and adapted it to dynamically retrieve the active row and to ecape quotes with `\`. However, if you this formula does not do what you desire, you can use any other formula and assign it programmatically as long as you mind escaping the inner quotes and using a dynamic row refernce.

Comment: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list (line 31, file "Code.gs")

Comment: instead of B3 in formula I change all to "O" and copied the formula in script but showing above mentioned error in line 31. Please note as I deleted some column and now the value of column is                                                                                                          var column = 16; // column P  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  var formulaValue = sheet.getRange(row, column).setFormula("=CHOOSE(LEFT(TEXT(O,"000000000000.00")..... (line 31)                      Please also let me know what is "+ row +" in your solution

Comment: row is the dynamically retrieved row in which the new form response data has been added. I assume that you do not always want to apply the formula to O3 but to the new added row respectively? I think your error comes from the fact that you did not escape the double quotes in `"000000000000.00"` in your new formula. If this is not the reason - update your question with your newest code that gives you the error and I will have a look.

Comment: I am unable to send you complete code in comments box neither in post my answer screen, can you share me your email address so I will send you the complete code.

Comment: You can simply post the link sharing link to your spreadsheet here - make sure that it does not contain private data that should not be publicly seen

Comment: below link is for your review. Please also advise for Column S and Column V which I forgot to mentioned as they both are also converting amount in words. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pBOXwVvzcAVdDBH5-iHr7upH1sjb98naGyxtphZKw2Q/edit#gid=1208915123

Comment: You would need to provide me access.

Comment: Dear, i had already provided and again given you access as editor.

Comment: I do not see any error in your code  and if I make a  copy of of your spreadsheet and use it as a destinaiton spreadsheet for my form - it sets the formula correctly and returns the value correctly. There was just a small typo from my side (It should be `sheet.getRange(row, column).setFormula(...` instead of `var formulaValue = sheet.getRange(row, column).setFormula(...` , but while it better to crrect this, it does not lead to errors. I assume you bound the funciton to an onForm submit trigger correctly?

Comment: Dear Ziganotschka, first of all accept my apology for late reply. Please note now error is gone and converting text perfectly except it is not accpeting the amount 1000000 (one million). and show blanck feeild. can you please check why it is not working , please also suggest how i can add multiple Amount field which i can convert in amount in words.

Comment: Your original question was about how to retrieve the result of a formula on form submit. I hope I answered this question correctly. Please mind that if you have additional questions, according to the guidelines of stackoveflow you should create a new post for this. This helps structuring posts in a clear way that also helps other users with similar questions to understand the single, specific question and solution of each post.

Comment: Dear Ziganotschka thank you all your kind support and patients. Just one think I dont understand why your given formula in script is different from the mentioned same on 12th Nov. post.

Comment: The formula in my solution is not mine - it is from the [url you mentioned in your question}(https://www.xelplus.com/Excel-Formula-Convert-Numbers-to-Words/). I only adjusted it conforming to usage in Apps Script - by escaping quotes where necessary and retrieving the row dynamically according to the row where the newest form response is inserted.

Comment: Dear thank you for all your kind support and also I am aware that it is not your formula but why it is not working in script whereas when applying without script it is working. if possible can you identify whats wrong.